# Unable to correct dependencies Update Debian 6 to 7

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, debian-wheezy

I tried updating debian 6 to 7 and getting trouble while running apt-get dist-upgrade.

What I have done is:
edit source.list, changed squeeze to whezzy

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

running

```
apt-get update # success
apt-get upgrade # success
apt-get dist-upgrade #failed

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 foo2zjs : Depends: printer-driver-foo2zjs but it is not installed
 gnome-system-tools : Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.99) but 0.96-4+squeeze2 is installed
                      Recommends: gnome-control-center (>= 1:2.10.1-1) but it is not installed
 grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 1.99-27+deb7u2) but 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1 is installed
 libpolkit-agent-1-0 : Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.105) but 0.96-4+squeeze2 is installed
 libpolkit-backend-1-0 : Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.104) but 0.96-4+squeeze2 is installed
 perl-modules : Depends: perl (>= 5.14.2-1) but 5.10.1-17squeeze6 is installed
 policykit-1 : Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.101) but 0.96-4+squeeze2 is installed
 policykit-1-gnome : Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (>= 0.99) but 0.96-4+squeeze2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

Fixing this with apt-get install -f fails and aptitude safe-upgrade --full-resolver is not able to resolve conflicts.

```
aptitude safe-upgrade --full-resolver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  accountsservice{a} acl{a} aptitude-common{a} at-spi2-core{a} colord{a} confget{a} console-setup-linux{ab} 
  cpp-4.7{a} crda{a} cryptsetup-bin{a} cups-filters{a} dconf-tools{a} enchant{a} firmware-linux-free{a} 
  folks-common{a} fonts-droid{a} fonts-freefont-ttf fuse{a} gconf-service{a} gcr{a} gir1.2-atk-1.0{a} 
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0{a} gir1.2-clutter-gst-1.0{a} gir1.2-cogl-1.0{a} gir1.2-coglpango-1.0{a} 
  gir1.2-evince-3.0{a} gir1.2-freedesktop{ab} gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0{a} gir1.2-glib-2.0{a} 
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0{a} gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10{a} gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10{a} gir1.2-gtk-3.0{a} 
  gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0{a} gir1.2-gtksource-3.0{a} gir1.2-json-1.0{a} gir1.2-pango-1.0{a} git-man{a} 
  glib-networking{a} glib-networking-common{a} glib-networking-services{a} gnome-desktop3-data{a} 
  gnome-icon-theme-symbolic{a} gnome-sushi{a} gnome-themes-standard{a} gnome-themes-standard-data{a} 
  grub-pc-bin{a} gsettings-desktop-schemas{a} gstreamer0.10-gconf{a} gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio{a} 
  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm{a} imagemagick-common{a} iw{a} kmod{a} krb5-locales{a} libapt-inst1.5{a} libapt-pkg4.12{a} 
  libasound2-plugins{a} libasprintf0c2{a} libatkmm-1.6-1{a} libatspi2.0-0{a} libaudiofile1{a} libavcodec53{a} 
  libavformat53{a} libavutil51{a} libbind9-80{a} libboost-iostreams1.49.0{a} libboost-program-options1.49.0{a} 
  libboost-thread1.49.0{a} libcamel-1.2-33{a} libcap2-bin{a} libchamplain-0.12-0{a} libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0{a} 
  libcheese-gtk21{a} libcheese3{a} libclutter-1.0-common{a} libclutter-gst-1.0-0{a} libclutter-gtk-1.0-0{a} 
  libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0{a} libclutter-imcontext-0.1-bin{a} libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0{a} libcogl-common{a} 
  libcogl-pango0{a} libcogl9{a} libcryptsetup4{a} libcupsfilters1{a} libdevmapper-event1.02.1{a} libdns88{a} 
  libdrm-nouveau1a{ab} libebackend-1.2-2{a} libebook-1.2-13{a} libecal-1.2-11{a} libedata-book-1.2-13{a} 
  libedata-cal-1.2-15{a} libedataserver-1.2-16{a} libedataserverui-3.0-1{a} libencode-locale-perl{a} 
  libept1.4.12{a} libescpr1{a} libevdocument3-4{a} libevent-2.0-5{a} libevview3-3{a} libexiv2-12{a} 
  libfile-listing-perl{a} libfolks-eds25{a} libfolks-telepathy25{a} libfolks25{a} libfribidi0{a} libgail-3-0{a} 
  libgck-1-0{a} libgconf-2-4{a} libgcr-3-1{a} libgcr-3-common{a} libgdata13{a} libgdiplus{a} libgeocode-glib0{a} 
  libgettextpo0{a} libgjs0b{a} libglapi-mesa{a} libglib2.0-bin{a} libgnome-bluetooth10{a} 
  libgnome-desktop-3-2{a} libgnome-keyring-common{a} libgnomekbd7{a} libgoa-1.0-0{a} libgoa-1.0-common{a} 
  libgs9{a} libgs9-common{a} libgssdp-1.0-3{a} libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0{a} libgtk-3-bin{a} 
  libgtkhtml-4.0-0{a} libgtkhtml-4.0-common{a} libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0{a} libgtksourceview-3.0-0{a} 
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common{a} libgupnp-1.0-4{a} libgusb2{a} libgweather-3-0{a} libgxps2{a} 
  libhtml-form-perl{a} libhttp-cookies-perl{a} libhttp-daemon-perl{a} libhttp-date-perl{a} 
  libhttp-message-perl{a} libhttp-negotiate-perl{a} libio-socket-ip-perl{a} libio-socket-ssl-perl{a} libisc84{a} 
  libisccc80{a} libisccfg82{a} libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0{a} libjim0debian2{a} libjson0{a} libkmod2{a} 
  libkpathsea6{a} liblensfun-data{a} liblensfun0{a} liblockfile-bin{a} liblvm2app2.2{a} 
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl{a} liblwp-protocol-https-perl{a} liblwres80{a} libmagick++5{a} libmagickcore5{a} 
  libmagickcore5-extra{a} libmagickwand5{a} libmetacity-private0a{ab} libmhash2{a} 
  libmission-control-plugins0{a} libmono-cairo4.0-cil{a} libmono-posix4.0-cil{a} libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil{a} 
  libmono-system-core4.0-cil{a} libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil{a} libmount1{a} libmozjs185-1.0{a} libmp3lame0{a} 
  libmpc2{a} libmtdev1{a} libmusicbrainz5-0{a} libmx-1.0-2{a} libmx-bin{a} libmx-common{a} 
  libnautilus-extension1a{ab} libnet-http-perl{a} libnet-ssleay-perl{a} libnetfilter-conntrack3{a} 
  libnl-3-200{a} libnl-genl-3-200{a} libnl-route-3-200{a} libnm-glib4{a} libnm-gtk-common{a} libnm-gtk0{a} 
  libnm-util2{a} liboauth0{a} libopenal-data{a} libopenal1{a} libopus0{a} libpackagekit-glib2-14{a} 
  libpam-cap{a} libpam-modules-bin{a} libperl5.14{a} libpipeline1{a} libpoppler-glib8{a} libpoppler19{a} 
  libpostproc52{a} libprocps0{a} libpst4{a} libpython2.7{a} libraptor2-0{a} librasqal3{a} libreadline5{a} 
  librest-0.7-0{a} librtmp0{a} libsamplerate0{a} libsane-common{a} libsane-extras-common{a} 
  libsemanage-common{a} libsemanage1{a} libsocket-perl{a} libsoundtouch0{a} libspandsp2{a} libssh2-1{a} 
  libswscale2{a} libsystemd-daemon0{a} libtelepathy-logger2{a} libtirpc1{a} libtokyocabinet9{a} 
  libtracker-sparql-0.14-0{a} libustr-1.0-1{a} libv4lconvert0{a} libva1{a} libvo-aacenc0{a} libvo-amrwbenc0{a} 
  libvpx1{a} libvte-2.90-9{a} libvte-2.90-common{a} libwacom-common{a} libwacom2{a} libwebkitgtk-1.0-0{a} 
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common{a} libwebkitgtk-3.0-0{a} libwebkitgtk-3.0-common{a} libwebrtc-audio-processing-0{a} 
  libwildmidi-config{a} libwpd-0.9-9{a} libwpg-0.2-2{a} libwww-robotrules-perl{a} libx264-123{a} libxcb-glx0{a} 
  libxcb-shape0{a} libxcb-util0{a} libxvidcore4{a} libyajl2{a} libyelp0{a} libzvbi-common{a} libzvbi0{a} 
  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64{a} linux-image-amd64 mc-data{a} mscompress{a} nsca-client{a} packagekit{a} 
  packagekit-backend-aptcc{a} packagekit-tools{a} poppler-data{a} printer-driver-all{a} printer-driver-c2050{a} 
  printer-driver-c2esp{a} printer-driver-cjet{a} printer-driver-escpr{a} printer-driver-foo2zjs{a} 
  printer-driver-gutenprint{a} printer-driver-hpcups{a} printer-driver-hpijs{a} printer-driver-m2300w{a} 
  printer-driver-min12xxw{a} printer-driver-pnm2ppa{a} printer-driver-postscript-hp{a} printer-driver-ptouch{a} 
  printer-driver-pxljr{a} printer-driver-sag-gdi{a} printer-driver-splix{a} pulseaudio{a} 
  pulseaudio-module-x11{a} pulseaudio-utils{a} python-aptdaemon.pkcompat{ab} python-dbus-dev{a} 
  python-debianbts{a} python-defer{a} python-fpconst{a} python-gi{a} python-gobject-2{a} python-packagekit{a} 
  python-pycurl{a} python-renderpm{a} python-reportlab{a} python-reportlab-accel{a} python-soappy{a} 
  python2.7{a} python2.7-minimal{a} rpcbind{ab} rtkit{a} samba-common{a} samba-common-bin{a} smbclient{a} 
  tcl8.5{a} usbutils{a} wireless-regdb{a} xserver-xorg-input-mouse{a} xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse{a} yelp-xsl{a} 
  zenity-common{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cpp-4.4{u} libgweather1{u} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alsa-base{b} alsa-utils apt apt-utils aptitude aspell base-files bash bind9-host binfmt-support bluez 
  bogofilter-bdb browser-plugin-gnash bsdmainutils ca-certificates ca-certificates-java cdrdao cheese-common 
  console-setup coreutils cpp cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-driver-gutenprint desktop-file-utils dmsetup 
  dnsmasq-base dnsutils docbook-xml dpkg e2fslibs e2fsprogs empathy-common esound-common evolution 
  evolution-common evolution-data-server{b} evolution-data-server-common evolution-plugins evolution-webcal 
  exim4 exim4-base exim4-daemon-light exiv2 file fontconfig foomatic-db foomatic-db-engine gconf2 gconf2-common 
  gdm3 gettext gettext-base ghostscript ghostscript-cups gimp-data git gnash gnash-common gnome-bluetooth 
  gnome-desktop-data gnome-doc-utils gnome-icon-theme gnome-keyring{b} gnome-power-manager gnome-session-bin 
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide grub-common grub-pc 
  gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good 
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-x gtk2-engines hpijs hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hwdata 
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao iceweasel ifupdown imagemagick info initramfs-tools initscripts inkscape iproute iptables 
  iputils-ping keyboard-configuration klibc-utils less libaa1 libart-2.0-2 libaspell15 libass4 libatasmart4 
  libatspi1.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavc1394-0 libblkid1 libbsd0 
  libcaca0 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libclutter-1.0-0 libcomerr2 libcroco3 
  libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3-gnutls libcwidget3 
  libdatrie1 libdc1394-22 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdirac-encoder0 libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdjvulibre21 libdrm-intel1 
  libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libdv4 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libedit2 libenchant1c2a libesd0 libevolution libexempi3 
  libexif12 libfaad2 libffi5 libfftw3-3 libflac8 libflite1 libfontenc1 libfs6 libgconf2-4 libgcrypt11 libgdbm3 
  libgimp2.0 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-cil libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglu1-mesa 
  libgnome-desktop-2-17 libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomekbd-common 
  libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-extra libgpg-error0 libgpgme11 libgpm2 libgsm1 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssglue1 
  libgssrpc4 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk2.0-cil libgtk2.0-common libgtkglext1 
  libgtkhtml3.14-19 libgtkimageview0 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgudev-1.0-0 libgutenprint2 libhpmud0 
  libhtml-parser-perl libice6 libidn11 libieee1284-3 libilmbase6 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1 libjpeg62 
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblcms1 libldap-2.4-2 
  liblocale-gettext-perl liblockfile1 liblqr-1-0 liblua5.1-0 libmagic1 libmms0 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil 
  libmono-addins0.2-cil libmpcdec6 libncurses5 libneon27-gnutls libnet-dbus-perl libnetpbm10 libnewt0.52 
  libnfsidmap2 libnl1 libnm-glib-vpn1 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libopenjpeg2 liborc-0.4-0 
  libpam-ck-connector libpam-modules libpangomm-1.4-1 libpaper1 libparted0debian1 libpcap0.8 libpci3 
  libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpng12-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0{b} libpopt0 libproxy0 libpstoedit0c2a 
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librdf0 librpcsecgss3 libsane libsane-extras libsane-hpaio 
  libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsdl1.2debian{b} libsensors4 libsepol1 libshout3 
  libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libslang2 libslv2-9 libsm6 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsnmp15 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 
  libsoup2.4-1 libspectre1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libsqlite3-0 libss2 libstartup-notification0 libsvga1 
  libsysfs2 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtalloc2 libtasn1-3 libtelepathy-glib0 libtext-charwidth-perl 
  libtext-iconv-perl libthai0 libtheora0 libts-0.0-0 libunique-1.0-0 libunistring0 libusb-0.1-4 libusb-1.0-0 
  libuuid-perl libuuid1 libv4l-0 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvte-common libvte9 libwavpack1 
  libwbclient0 libwildmidi1 libwmf-bin libwnck22 libwrap0 libwww-perl libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 
  libxapian22 libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-render0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 
  libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbfile1 libxml-parser-perl libxmu6 libxmuu1 
  libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxres1 libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxxf86dga1 
  libxxf86vm1 libzbar0 linux-image-2.6-amd64 lsb-release man-db mc menu metacity metacity-common min12xxw 
  modemmanager module-init-tools mount mousetweaks mutt nano nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-sendto 
  nautilus-sendto-empathy ncurses-bin netbase netpbm network-manager network-manager-gnome nfs-common 
  notification-daemon nsca ntfs-3g{b} obex-data-server obexd-client openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib 
  openssh-client openssh-server openssl passwd pciutils perl perl-base perlmagick pnm2ppa poppler-utils procps 
  psmisc python python-apt python-aptdaemon python-chardet python-dbus python-debian python-gobject 
  python-imaging python-libxml2 python-lxml python-minimal python-pexpect python-reportbug 
  python-software-properties python-xapian python2.6 python2.6-minimal reportbug rsync rsyslog seahorse 
  sgml-base sgml-data sysvinit tasksel tcl telepathy-mission-control-5 tmux ttf-freefont udisks ufraw-batch 
  update-notifier-common upower usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data util-linux vim vim-common vim-runtime 
  vim-tiny w3m wget whiptail wpasupplicant x11-apps x11-utils xml-core xorg xsane xsane-common xserver-xorg 
  xserver-xorg-core{b} xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-apm xserver-xorg-video-ark xserver-xorg-video-ati 
  xserver-xorg-video-chips xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-i128 
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga xserver-xorg-video-neomagic 
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon 
  xserver-xorg-video-rendition xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-s3virge xserver-xorg-video-savage 
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx 
  xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-tseng xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware 
  xserver-xorg-video-voodoo xterm xz-utils yelp zenity 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  foo2zjs gnome-system-tools grub2-common libmono-corlib2.0-cil libmono-posix2.0-cil libmono-security2.0-cil 
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system2.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil 
  libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libswitch-perl mono-gac mono-runtime perl-modules policykit-1 
  policykit-1-gnome 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  aptitude-doc-cs aptitude-doc-en aptitude-doc-es aptitude-doc-fi aptitude-doc-fr aptitude-doc-it 
  aptitude-doc-ja gimp gnome-control-center gnome-session gnome-session-fallback libatm1 
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl lxsession openbox uuid-runtime xfce4-session 
463 packages upgraded, 314 newly installed, 2 to remove and 155 not upgraded.
Need to get 505 MB of archives. After unpacking 488 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  python-pyorbit: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  python-aptdaemon.pkcompat: Conflicts: packagekit but 0.7.6-3 is to be installed.
  libgnome2-vfs-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 which is a virtual package.
  libgtkhtml-editor0: Depends: libgtkhtml3.14-19 (< 3.31) but 3.32.2-2.1 is to be installed.
  cheese: Depends: cheese-common (= 2.30.1-2) but 3.4.2-2 is to be installed.
  python-openssl: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  libcairo-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 which is a virtual package.
  libgtk2-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 which is a virtual package.
  xserver-xorg-core: Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-6 which is a virtual package.
  libpython2.6: Depends: python2.6 (= 2.6.6-8+deb6u3) but 2.6.8-1.1 is to be installed.
  gir1.2-freedesktop: Conflicts: gir1.0-freedesktop but 0.6.14-1+b1 is installed.
  python-httplib2: Breaks: python (>= 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  evolution-exchange: Depends: libgtkhtml3.14-19 (< 3.31) but 3.32.2-2.1 is to be installed.
                      Depends: evolution (< 2.31.0) but 3.4.4-3 is to be installed.
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0: Breaks: libpolkit-gtk-1-0 (< 0.99) but 0.96-3 is installed.
  python-zope.interface: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  python-twisted-conch: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  empathy: Depends: empathy-common (= 2.30.3-1) but 3.4.2.3-2+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  console-setup-linux: Breaks: console-terminus but 4.30-2 is installed.
  gdebi-core: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  python-twisted-web: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  gnome-keyring: Breaks: seahorse-plugins (< 3.0) but 2.30.1-3 is installed.
  libpango-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 which is a virtual package.
  python-brlapi: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  libsdl1.2debian: Conflicts: libsdl1.2debian-alsa but 1.2.14-6.1 is installed.
  libmetacity-private0a: Breaks: libmetacity-private0 but 1:2.30.1-3 is installed.
  libept1: Depends: libapt-pkg4.10 which is a virtual package.
  python-gtkglext1: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  gconf-defaults-service: Depends: gconf2-common (< 2.29) but 3.2.5-1+build1 is to be installed.
  python-cairo: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  libdrm-nouveau1a: Conflicts: libdrm-nouveau1 but 2.4.21-1~squeeze3 is installed.
  libgnome2-canvas-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 which is a virtual package.
  aptdaemon: Depends: python-aptdaemon (= 0.31+bzr413-1.1) but 0.45-2 is to be installed.
  python-tagpy: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  xserver-xorg-video-nv: Depends: xorg-video-abi-6.0 which is a virtual package.
  python-twisted-core: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  libglib-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.1 which is a virtual package.
  libfont-freetype-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 which is a virtual package.
  libperl5.10: Depends: perl-base (= 5.10.1-17squeeze6) but 5.14.2-21+deb7u2 is to be installed.
  synaptic: Depends: libapt-inst1.2 which is a virtual package.
            Depends: libapt-pkg4.10 which is a virtual package.
  rpcbind: Conflicts: portmap but 6.0.0-2 is installed.
  alsa-base: Breaks: linux-sound-base but 1.0.23+dfsg-2 is installed.
  python-gst0.10: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  libgnome2-perl: Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 which is a virtual package.
  python-markupsafe: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  evolution-data-server: Breaks: libebook1.2-9 (< 2.32) but 2.30.3-2+squeeze1 is installed.
                         Breaks: libecal1.2-7 (< 2.32) but 2.30.3-2+squeeze1 is installed.
  libmetacity-private0: Depends: metacity-common (< 1:2.31) but 1:2.34.3-4 is to be installed.
  python-pysqlite2: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
  libnautilus-extension1a: Conflicts: libnautilus-extension1 but 2.30.1-2squeeze2 is installed.
  ntfs-3g: Conflicts: libntfs-3g75 but 1:2010.3.6-1 is installed.
  python-gconf: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
                Depends: python2.5-gobject which is a virtual package.
  python-crypto: Depends: python (< 2.7) but 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 is to be installed.
open: 6838; closed: 10653; defer: 22; conflict: 29                                                                  o
No solution found within the allotted time.  Try harder? [Y/n]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Update

```
# dpkg -C
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 mono-runtime         Mono runtime
 perl-modules         Core Perl modules
 libmono-posix2.0-cil Mono.Posix library (for CLI 2.0)
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil Mono System.Configuration library (for CLI
 libswitch-perl       switch statement for Perl
 libpolkit-agent-1-0  PolicyKit Authentication Agent API
 foo2zjs              transitional dummy package for foo2zjs printer driver
 policykit-1-gnome    GNOME authentication agent for PolicyKit-1
 libmono-system4.0-cil Mono System libraries (for CLI 4.0)
 libmono-system-security4.0-cil Mono System.Security library (for CLI 4.0)
 libpolkit-backend-1-0 PolicyKit backend API
 gnome-system-tools   Cross-platform configuration utilities for GNOME
 libmono-security2.0-cil Mono Security library (for CLI 2.0)
 grub2-common         GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
 libmono-system2.0-cil Mono System libraries (for CLI 2.0)
 libmono-corlib2.0-cil Mono core library (for CLI 2.0)
 policykit-1          framework for managing administrative policies and privil

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 mono-gac             Mono GAC tool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Between `update` and `dist-upgrade`, there is no need to an `upgrade`, although it shouldn't kill so many things.
2. You should check with a `dpkg -C` if every package was installed okay on the system. If not, then you should fix these problems first. I am waiting your `dpkg -C` output.
3. In such cases, there are many things which can be done. The first were to simply pick a single package, for example, see the first, the `foo2zjs`. Insted of a dist-upgrade, now try a simple `apt-get install foo2zjs`. It will probably answer, that it can't be installed because its dependency, `printer-driver-foo2zjs` is missing. Then try to install `printer-driver-foo2zjs`, and you will see, what happens (and I am also very curious :-) ).

There is not really uncommon, that some debian mirror is only synchronized partially, and that can such "not found" and "missing package" like errors cause.

There is another possibility, that your old squeeze wasn't upgraded to the last stable update. It is not really good idea, because the last updates of a debian release targetting mostly exactly the seamless update to the next release, and maybe there are some "hole" in the dependencies if you don't do that.

Anyways, maybe there weren't a bad idea to press "Y" for the "Try harder?" question at the end. It is not a really big problem if some software is maybe deleted, if something is missing, you will be able to reinstall them with some apt-get install commands.

But what the most important thing is: it is not windows. On linux, you *can* safely remove/reinstall system components, I did already even architectural change with dist-upgrade (i.e. upgrading an i386 to an x86_64), we can even change a debian to an ubuntu with dist-upgrade, the only thing is important: you need to know, how apt works, and be curious (some tricky `dpkg --force-all --purge ...` can also fix a much).

---

If your `dpkg -C` doesn't give you a full clean system, you should first fix that, and not your system upgrade. A `dpkg --configure -a` retries the configuration of your packages, which will give you interesting error messages, too.

If it also doesn't work, you can do a forced removal of the bad packages with a `dpkg --force-all --purge bad_package`.

If nothing works to remove a hardly damaged package, as an ultima ratio, you can simply delete its postremoval and preremoval scripts with `rm -vf /var/lib/dpkg/info/<badly_damaged_package_name>*rm`.

Comment: I mixed it a litte bit up, of couse I did upgrade before update.

I updated my initial post for dpgk -C output

"Try harder" always fails, no solution to do this.

Comment: @Zack I extended my answer. If your dpkg -C isn't clean, first handle this problem and continue your update only after.

Comment: Thanks you! Works after fixing missing things a couple of times.

Comment: @Zack Good :-) You can even dist-upgrade a debian to ubuntu, and vice versa. Since there is support on debian to install packages to alien architectures and run them by the qemu emulator, you can even dist-upgrade a distro to an architecture which isn't supported by your cpu :-)