# libphp5.so is missing, dependency problems

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, debian-wheezy

after some updates my Debian server (running Apache 2.2) seems to miss the `libphp5.so`. Starting Apache leads to the error message

```
sudo service apache2 restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 244 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

Trying to reinstall libapache5 however lead to

```
 sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 215-5+b1) but 215-6 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and `apt-get -f install` couldn't solve the problem. It wants to install the package `udev` but ends up with an error

```
insserv: script apache: service apache2 already provided!
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_215-6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what to do. How can I get my Apache running again?

---

**Edit**

```
dpkg -C
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 dictionaries-common  Common utilities for spelling dictionary tools
 dovecot-core         secure POP3/IMAP server - core files
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if this sharedlib is really missing (there is some case if its load fails with this error even if the file is on your system), with an `ls -ldL /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`. Probably yes, it is missing, so we go further on this branch.
2. Your packages seem a little bit problematic. With a `dpkg -C` you can check if there are some damaged packages on your system. If yes, you had to solve this problem first.
3. Try an `apt-get --reinstall install libapache2-mod-php5`. The key is the `--reinstall` flag, without it nothing happened even if your system is in an undamaged state.
4. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/647772/unable-to-correct-dependencies-update-debian-6-to-7/647780#647780) you can find my other answer, which can provide useful commands to you, although the original question was different: he wanted to fix a failed upgrade, you want to fix your apache php5 module. But the problem is essentially the same: both of you want to fix the inconsistent state of a debian/ubuntu system.

---

Extension reacting comment: then you should have a clear `dpkg -C` output (no damaged packages). Next what I can see is that you have probably some type of inconsistence between your package versions and between your actual debian(ubuntu) repository. First check if you have installed all of the latest updates: `apt-get update`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

If works, you are ready. If not, then some tricky solution is probably needed. In your place I removed some problematic packages (`dpkg --purge` for induvidual packages, or `apt-get --purge remove` to remove packages with all of their dependencies), and then tried to reinstall them. If nothing works, I removed the whole apache2 & php thing.

But beware: removing packages by purging deletes their configuration in `/etc` as well. Make a backup from your whole `/etc` (or at least from `/etc/apache2`) before that!

P.s. It is not impossible, that your actual debian mirror isn't really okay. What is in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to configure some packages that were listed by dpkg -C. However, I can't reconfigure two of them and nearly everything I do with apt-get gives me the error "libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211   Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 215-5+b1) but 215-6 is to be installed"